# Allow a trailing slash in a Clojure function name

Tags: clojure

For a DSL I'm implementing, I'd like to create a `=/` function (which would be like `not=`).
Is it possible to tell the reader to allow me to do this?

My guess is "No. You dream.", but who knows…

```
user=> =/
RuntimeException Invalid token: =/  clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)

user=> (def =/ 1)
RuntimeException Invalid token: =/  clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)
1
RuntimeException Unmatched delimiter: )  clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)

user=> (defn =/ [x y] (not= x y))
RuntimeException Invalid token: =/  clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: y in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0:0) 
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: y in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:16:16) 
RuntimeException Unmatched delimiter: )  clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)
```

Answer (score 8):

The [Clojure Reader](http://clojure.org/reference/reader#_symbols) treats slashes in a special way:

> '/' has special meaning, it can be used once in the middle of a symbol to separate the namespace from the name, e.g. my-namespace/foo. '/' by itself names the division function.

So you won't be able to include the slash in the name of your function as the reader interprets it as the designation of a namespace.

the non obvious part is that when you type:

```
(defn =/ ...)
```

the symbol `=/` is being expanded by the reader to its fully namespace qualified name of:

```
 my.org.namespace/=/
```

which violates the "one slash per name" rule.

Comment: mind if I merge these answers, since they start off the same?

Comment: Ha!  No prob, Arthur.

Comment: I'm pretty suspicious of the "being expanded by the reader" part of this explanation. The reader doesn't expand anything unless you're using a backtick form.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in common lisp, using "reader macros" functionality. However,
from: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_Clojure/Reader_Macros

> At this time, Clojure does not allow you to define your own reader macros, but this may change in the future.